# Can someone tell me how to solve vector integral questions

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Hey I have the following question, but I am not sure how to solve it. Can someone please either show me how to solve this question or give me a link to websites which show me how to solve integrals of vectors and transformation please.

The question is as following: 
[question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QE3OJ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a beginning line integral. All you need to do is plug in stuff.  $$d\mathbf{r} = dx \mathbf{\hat i}+ dy \mathbf{\hat j}$$ and $dy = 2x \; dx$, and $y= x^2$.  Plug in stuff until all the $y$'s are gone and then integrate from $x=0$ to $x=2$.

If you want to google, try "*Line integral*."